# Haxe - use string as variable name with DynamicAccess

Tags: haxe

I am trying to use a string ('npcName') as a variable name. So far I have tried casting dialogMap into a DynamicAccess object, but it gives me the error 'Invalid array access' when I try this:

```
    var npcName:String = 'TestNPC';
    var casted = (cast Registry.dialogMap:haxe.DynamicAccess<Dynamic>);
    var tempname = casted[root.npcName[0].message];
    trace(tempname);
```

'dialogMap' is an empty map which I want to fill like so:

```
Registry.dialogMap['message'] = root.npcName[0].message;
```

How can I use npcName, a string, in the above line of code? Is there a way to transform the string into something usable? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `haxe.DynamicAccess` doesn't have array access (like `map[key]`), but is an abstract type for working with anonymous structures that are intended to hold collections of objects by the string key. It is designed to work with `map.get(key)` and `map.set(key)`. It is basically a nicer wrapper around `Reflect.field` and `Reflect.setField` and does some safety checks with `Reflect.hasField`.

```
    var variable = "my_key";
    var value = 123;

    var dynamicMap = new haxe.DynamicAccess<Dynamic>();
    dynamicMap.set(variable, value);
```

I'm noticing you are doing very much cast and dynamic, so *untyped* code, which is a bit of contradiction in a *typed* language. What is the actual type of dialogMap?

Not sure you are aware of it but, Haxe has its own maps, which are fully typed, so you don't need casts.

```
    var map = new Map<String, Int>();
    map[variable] = value;
```

I think [this article](http://code.haxe.org/category/beginner/string-variable-reflection.html) helps understanding how to work with dynamic (untyped) objects.

> Tip; for testing such small functionalities you can doodle around on the try.haxe site : http://try.haxe.org/#4B84E

Hope this helps, otherwise here is some relevant documentation:

- http://api.haxe.org/haxe/DynamicAccess.html
- https://haxe.org/manual/std-reflection.html
- https://haxe.org/manual/types-dynamic.html
- http://code.haxe.org/category/beginner/string-variable-reflection.html